# Notice: get_product is deprecated since version 3.0! Use wc_get_product instead

Tags: woocommerce

I get this error message:

> Notice: get_product is deprecated since version 3.0! Use wc_get_product instead.

I'm using a theme created by my boss and have to update it, I have never done that before and have no idea on how to do that.

I have tried to update price.php and the abstract-wc-product.php. But I still get the error message. Do anyone know how to fix this?

(Image in Norwegian)

[image]

Comment: first step is to find which template using  get_product function and then you can posted here so we can help you modify that template

Answer (score 0):

Instead of

```php
$product->get_display_price()
```

Use

```php
wc_get_price_to_display($product)
```

Answer (score -2):

Try Adding or updating your `wp-config` file
Set `wp-debug` to `False`.

```
define('WP_DEBUG', true); to define('WP_DEBUG', false);
```